# jQuery fadeIn not working as expected

Tags: jquery

When trying to do a simple `fadeIn` I am getting this error in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: ".desc_zidane".fadeIn is not a function

```
<div class="desc_zidane"></div>
```

```css
.desc_zidane {
    display: none;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    position: abolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".char1").click(function() {
        (".desc_zidane").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

If you need to see more code, the site can be view here: http://www.matthewrdaniels.com/ff9

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: $(".desc_zidane").fadeIn(500);  forgot $ ..

Comment: doh! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna kick yourself after this one, you just forgot the $.
It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".char1").click(function() {
        $(".desc_zidane").fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe it was that simple.